# Managing opt-outs coming in via list-unsubscribe header

Tags: marketing-cloud, unsubscribe

**Background:** we are using a custom un-subscription center through a page running on external SF platform and all opt outs goes directly in to that master SF system. From marketing(SFMC) perspective, we can include this custom link in all commercial emails (so far good!!), But facing a challenge to understand how can handle the another standard **list-unsubscribe header** that appears in email clients gmail or IOS etc. which marketing cloud platform adds for any commercials emails(using send classification comm)

**Problem statement:** what are the possibilities to handle this deviation behavior(list-unsubscribe one) as its quite common use-case to have custom unsubs center?

what are the recommended / best practices ?

1. Get this option **disabled** by contacting marketing cloud support team Or possibility to replace this link with custom url but i read sfmc doesn't http option only 'mailto' so i think woudnt be an option
2. Rather use **transactional send classification** for commercials emails rand include custom link in all emails to surface option to customer to opt out.
3. Handle this unsubscribe response via reply to address set up **Reply Mail Management**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **No** - This will most definitely affect your deliverability and might even block your sender with some ISPs, who simply refuse letting emails through without this header.
2. **No** - Using a transactional send classification to send non-transactional mail would result in marketing mail being sent to recipients whose status is set to Unsubscribed in All subs. This is obviously not something you want to do, as it not only goes agains recommendations, but is also illegal.
3. **No** - this will also be an overly complex solution.

My approach would be to :

1. Query Unsubscribe and ListSubscribers data views, to identify the recipients who used list-unsubscribe option.
2. Output the result into a data extension
3. Run an SSJS activity which calls an endpoint on the platform responsible for consent management, in order to unsubscribe
4. Remember to update the status in All Subscribers to active once they opt back in again.

Comment: Thank you very much @Lukas Lunow for adding insights, really helped to validate.

Comment: You're welcome, @mohitchhabra - remember to upvote/accept

Comment: @LukasLunow. Do you know if we can change the link to a custom link?

Comment: @JuanJardim - you can ask support to update the list-unsubscribe header to a URL instead of an email address. I've heard this is possible in some cases.

Comment: Can you elaborate how the Unsubscribe and the ListSubscribers data views would provide this information?  Wouldn't the contact be removed from the ListSubscribers DV as soon as the contact unsubscribes?

Comment: @mohitchhabra  Were you ever able to resolve this situation? I have a similar issue that I am trying to tackle, to identify which users used the List-Unsubscribe header, but cannot understand how the accepted proposal will work.   When the user unsubscribes, I would expect that both lists would be updated the same way so how will this isolate those that use the list-unsubscribe header?